# Import CSV file from Google Cloud Storage to Google Cloud SQL using GCP Workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, google-cloud-sql, google-iam

I am writing a workflow to import csv into cloud sql (my_sql instance) from GCS bucket. I am using sql admin api v1 to perform import. Following is my workflow code:

```
main:
  params: [event]
  steps:
  - log_event:
      call: sys.log
      args:
          text: ${event}
          severity: INFO
  - extract_bucket_and_file:
      assign:
        - bucket: ${event.data.bucket}
        - file: ${event.data.name}
  - init:
      assign:
        - project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
        - instance: "xxx-instance"
        - database_name: "xxx-db"    
  - start_sql_instance:
      call: googleapis.sqladmin.v1.instances.patch
      args:
          instance: ${instance}
          project: ${project_id}
          body:
              settings:
                activationPolicy: 'ALWAYS'
      result: startSqlResponse
  - log_start_sql_instance_response:
      call: sys.log
      args:
          text: ${startSqlResponse}
          severity: INFO
  - import_data:
      call: http.post
      args: 
        url: ${"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"+project_id+"/instances/"+instance+"/import"}
        auth:
          type: OAuth2
        body:
          importContext:
            fileType: CSV
            uri: gs://${bucket}/${file}
            database: ${database_name}
            kind: sql#importContext
            csvImportOptions:
              table: 'xxx'
      result: importResponse
  - log_import_data_response:
      call: sys.log
      args:
          text: ${importResponse}
          severity: INFO                          
  - the_end:
      return: "SUCCESS"
```

Error I am getting when executing this workflow is as follows:

```
HTTP server responded with error code 403
in step "import_data", routine "main", line: 33
{
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.",
          "reason": "notAuthorized"
        }
      ],
      "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."
    }
  },
  "code": 403,
  "headers": {
    "Alt-Svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
    "Cache-Control": "private",
    "Content-Length": "328",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Date": "Wed, 13 Sep 2023 05:47:04 GMT",
    "Server": "ESF",
    "Vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-Xss-Protection": "0"
  },
  "message": "HTTP server responded with error code 403",
  "tags": [
    "HttpError"
  ]
}
```

Based on the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/import-export-csv#import_data_to) it suggests to grant `Storage Object Admin` for convenience to `Cloud SQL Instance Service Account`, which you can get from instance console or gcloud command `gcloud sql instances describe xxx-instance`. I did exactly what document says but I am still getting the 403 error.

[image: Permissions]

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me where I am going wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Cloud SQL error but a workflow error. The Workflow service account does not have the permission to import data in Cloud SQL.

Grant the Cloud SQL admin role on the workflow service account.

Comment: Even that has storage admin role. 

My Workflow service account has all the following roles:
Cloud Run Invoker
Cloud SQL Admin
Eventarc Event Receiver
Pub/Sub Publisher
Storage Admin
Workflows Invoker

Comment: I wrote [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/replicate-data-from-bigquery-to-cloud-sql-2b23a08c52b1) and you have the associated [github repo](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/workflow-bq-to-cloudsql/blob/main/README.md) where instruction are in it. Your permission are enough, or you are missing something (wrong service account, wrong log entry,...)

Comment: I checked almost everything, I can't really find a reason for it. I destroyed resources and then re-created them but no luck so far. Is there a way to debug more for instance, I am really interested in finding that what particular service account is being used by GCP when executing?

Comment: I fixed it. I am getting this error not due to permission issues but due to string interpolation. It was my stupid that I was passing incorrect bucket URI. This is incorrect: `gs://${bucket}/${file}`.  The correct way is. ${"gs://"+bucket+"/"+file}.